# How to fetch EKS kubernetes cluster details to my Spring Boot application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have a kubernetes cluster on Amazon EKS (Elastic Kubernetes Service) and I have a spring boot application.

I want to see the details of my cluster like the namespaces, nodes, pods, services, etc into the console of my spring boot application.

I want to write a spring boot API which I can hit and I can get the cluster details on my console.

What is the way to do it?

Is there any API or documentation available on this?